# Why does .save work in Mongoose but not an .update with an upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My save is:

```
        tx = new Transaction transaction

        tx.save (err) ->
            console.log err
            cb err
```

That saves just fine.

```
    Transaction.update transaction, {upsert: true}, (err, num, raw) ->
      console.log err
      console.log num
      console.log raw
```

However, my update won't upsert a document. Furthermore, it returns no `err` and 0 for `num`. This is with `"mongoose": "~3.8.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to the `update` function is the query to match one or more documents ([reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)).

I'd expect the call to `Transaction.update` to only include the document's `_id`, rather than the entire object. The second parameter is either the entire document or an object using update operators.

It's possible you want:

```
Transaction.update _id : transaction._id, transaction, upsert: true, 
   (err, num, raw)->
```

Or, maybe you want to set specific properties of that transaction using one of the documented [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/).

```
Transaction.update  _id : transaction._id,  $set :  { amount : 500 } ,
      upsert : true, (err, num, raw) ->
```